Tableau data source not updating through hyper API
I have a workbook containing one data source being an extract file, I'm trying to update this file through hyper API, this is how my code looks like :
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        # Get the project ID
        all_projects, pagination_item = server.projects.get()
        project_id = next(project.id for project in all_projects if project.name == project_name)

        # Find the workbook
        all_workbooks, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get()
        print("Workbooks available:")
        for workbook in all_workbooks:
            print(f"Workbook name: {workbook.name}, Workbook ID: {workbook.id}")

        workbook = next(workbook for workbook in all_workbooks if workbook.name == workbook_name)

        # Get the workbook's data sources
        server.workbooks.populate_connections(workbook)
        data_source = next(ds for ds in workbook.connections if ds.datasource_name == data_source_name)

        # Update the data source with the new file
        new_data_source = TSC.DatasourceItem(project_id, name=data_source.datasource_name)
        new_data_source = server.datasources.publish(new_data_source, local_file_path, 
        TSC.Server.PublishMode.Overwrite)

        #  Refresh the workbook to reflect the new data
        server.workbooks.refresh(workbook.id)
        print(f"Workbook {workbook.name} (ID: {workbook.id}) has been refreshed.")
 
        print("Data source updated and workbook refreshed.")

this code executes correctly but when i go to my tableau server i don't see any changes, i also find the output.hyper file that i'm trying to push in the project folder like so:

after i run the code i also get a notification saying that the workbook is out of date but clicking refresh doesn't do anything either.
Am i doing something wrong here?

When you say "update" are you trying to change the datasource as a whole or run an extract refresh to get the most recent data for the existing datasource?

@MUFF. i would prefer to change the datasource as whole and keep it live, from what i've seen it's likely not possible. what i've settled for is create a template workbook and create a copy of it with the new data and publish it while overwriting the old workbook which seems to work fairly well.

So that I am clear; you are trying to change the extract to a live connection via the API?
